# HealthKit iTunes Connect entitlement error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I had enabled health kit capability in Xcode and HealthKit service in Developer center at some point for my app. But then I disabled it right away as I decided to not include it. My app doesn't have any HealthKit related stuff in it, I have disabled the capability and also disabled it in developer center. However, when I try to submit my app in iTunes connect, it gives me error:

> Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.healthkit] must have a privacy policy URL for [English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary.

When validating the app in Xcode, it still shows me health kit entitlement: com.apple.developer.healthkit

Any idea how I can completely get rid of this entitlement from my app? I have been struggling for over a day now :(

NOTE: this is a new app, it's not available in the app store yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem, and I finally fixed it. Be sure that you remove any reference to HealthKit not only in your app but also in your developer profile for this app.

**Go To the developer portal**

1. Click the App IDs link on the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles developer page
2. Select the App ID you are using in your app
3. Click the Edit button
4. If HealthKit is enabled, disable it and click the Done button
5. Regenerate all provisioning profiles using that App ID

**Open Xcode**

6. Turn Healtkit to off in your project  (it looks like you already did it, I write it for the other)
7. Check you have no trace of Healtkit in your entitlement file, plist file and HealthKit is not in your Frameworks.
8. select Xcode > Preferences > Accounts. Select your team and click View Details
9. Click the refresh button in the bottom left corner to refresh your provisioning profiles
10. Restart Xcode and rebuild your project
11. Submit your app. During the submit process, you should not see the Healtkit Entitlement anymore.

NB : If you still face the problem, I suggest you to delete all your provisioning profile at step 5 and try again. Don't forgot to restart XCode.

Answer (score 8):

There is option of Privacy Policy URL inside the APP, just fill that URL with the URL of your company and save and submit the application.

Comment: But I don't have health kit in my app, so I don't want to add a privacy policy. If I fill the url with my company url, that would require me to also host a privacy policy which I don't have.

Comment: This should be the correct answer if you want to use healthkit for your app.

Comment: Where is this option? In plist file or where?

Comment: @daleijn It's in **iTunes Connect**, in the *App Store Information* tab. Just filling the *Privacy Policy URL* field should do the trick.